# Google Firebase SAML Auth: Getting 400 Error INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE: has no assertions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, saml, saml-2.0

I am trying to connect my Firebase application with Stanford's SUNet as an identity provider. I'm getting a 400 response after successful login via popup. Relevant code pasted below. Has anyone seen this before?

```
  const samlLogin = (samlProvider) => () => {
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const provider = new firebase.auth.SAMLAuthProvider(samlProvider);
    auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then((userCredential) => {
      console.log(userCredential);
      onSuccess(userCredential.user);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      setLoading(false);
      setErrorText('Something went wrong. Try again or contact support.')
    });
  }
```

`domain: "global" message: "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Invalid Response: has no assertions." reason: "invalid"`

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you have signed requests turned on (see https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/saml#signing_requests) but the IdP is not configured for request signing.

Assuming that's the cause, you either need to configure your IdP for signed requests (which is better security), or turn them off in GCP Identity Platform.

Comment: I never turned it on and even don'T find something in the GCP Identity Platform about that if it's on or off. Can you please share a hint where to find this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of January 2024, integrating Firebase with a Shibboleth IdP for SAML appears impossible. Shibboleth, widely used by universities, encrypts attributes by default, and most institutions are unable or unwilling to disable this. While Firebase allows for request signing and SPI certificate acquisition via its API [1], it doesn't support attribute decryption. Consequently, Shibboleth cannot import an XML without an encryption certificate, and Firebase's lack of decryption capabilities leads to integration failure.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/saml#signing_requests